# What should I use: security group or WAF Web ACL

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have EKS cluster that uses Application Load Balancer (ALB).

ALB has security group with only two ip addresses whitelisted.
I need to whitelist the requests not only on IP address level but on country AND IP address level.
I created waf rule groups with specific country, ip set with those two ip addresses and web acl without deleting existing security group on ALB.

In that case the requests reach my endpoint but only on IP address level, not on country level.
So, please, help me to understand how to work with web acl and security group on ALB? What should I choose?
May be I need to delete the security group from ALB and use **only** web acl?

Answer (score 0):

You may choose aws WAF on you ALB for specific country. Here is the link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-waf.html